# GNU Radio history

Tags: gnuradio

I have a general work function for which I will use GNU Radio's history functionality. In the block's constructor, I call `set_history( m )`. I cast the input buffer in the standard way:

```
  const float *in = (const float *) input_items[0];
```

My question is wheere `in[0]` refers to in the buffer. It would make sense to me that `noutput_items` is the number of *new* items for the block to consume and `ninput_items[0]` refers to the total number of data in the buffer. So, `in[noutput_items-1]` is the last element of the array, `in[0]` is the start of the *new* items, and the `in[-m]` refers to the beginning of the history block. Thus, `ninput_items[0]` is greater than or equal to `m + noutput_items`.

I don't know if this assumption is true and would be pleased if someone knew how this works. The GNU Radio API is somewhat vague in this respect. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Tom Rondeau helped answer this question on the [GNU Radio wiki](http://gnuradio.org). `in[0]` refers to the beginning of the history. In order to make `in[0]` refer the beginning of the *new* data, declare `in` this way:

```
const float *in = (const float *) &((const float*)input_items[0])[history()-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness of @Chris, `set_history()` refers to the number of **items**, just like the `noutput_itmes` parameter.

`in[0]` refers to the first item of the history. In order to skip the history and get the first new item this is the proper way:

`const <TYPE> *in = (const <TYPE> *) &((const <TYPE>*)input_items[0])[(history()-1) * VEC_SIZE];`

`VEC_SIZE` refers to the number of samples of type  that was specified at the input signature.

So for example if the input signature of a block is

`io_signature::make(1, 1, vec_len * sizeof(float))`

each item is constructed from `vec_len` float numbers. The history can properly be skipped with:

`const float *in_new = (const float *) &((const float*)input_items[0])[(history()-1) * vec_len]`;